# How to read JSON object in PHP

Tags: php, json

This is my JSON object:

```
<pre>
stdClass Object
(
[user] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => Bob Smith
        [age] => 47
    )

[0] => CEO
[1] => USA
)
</pre>
```

How to read these last two output:

```
[0] => CEO<br/>
[1] => USA<br/>
```

like I am reading this:

```
<pre>
$res = json_decode($json_data);
echo $res->user->name; //out : Bob Smith
</pre>
```

Comment: This doesn't look like json.

Comment: This structure looks not okay, I tried to display it and got this error : `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` because of your `[0]` and `[1]` index

Comment: that's a php stdClass, to read what you're asking, do `$json_data[0]` and `$json_data[1]` respectively

Comment: $res is JSON Object. Is there any way two read [0] => CEO, 
[1] => USA using $res.

I am trying $res[0] or $res[1] but having error : 
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: There is no such thing as a *"JSON object"*. [JSON](http://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure (usually an object or an array). It needs to be decoded (using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)) to get back the data structure used to create it (and it is not JSON at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reading that indexes you have to:

```
echo $res->{"0"};
```

Using [ ] brackets will threat it as an array, and you cannot -> directly a number